# netbeans platform no persistence provider for entitymanager named

Tags: java, netbeans, persistence, eclipselink, entitymanager

When I run my application in Netbeans, I have no problem, but when I run it using java -jar filename.jar, then I get the following:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\ksk>java -jar C:\Users\ksk\Documents\Testing\StateMachine.jar

Oct 16, 2013 10:06:01 AM dtc.fileops.properties.MEISDirectoryManager createDirectories
INFO: Found MEIS Directory: C:\Users\ksk\MEIS
Trying config file in C:\Users\ksk\MEIS\StationApplication\config.txt
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.factoryserviceslibrary.db.EMGR.getInstance(EMGR.java:24)
        at statemachine.Context.startEMGR(Context.java:412)
        at statemachine.Main$3.run(Main.java:277)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named PU
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:85)
        at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)
        at com.factoryserviceslibrary.db.EMGR.startEMGR(EMGR.java:41)
        at com.factoryserviceslibrary.db.EMGR.<init>(EMGR.java:32)
        at com.factoryserviceslibrary.db.EMGR.<init>(EMGR.java:16)
        at com.factoryserviceslibrary.db.EMGR$SingletonHolder.<clinit>(EMGR.java:64)
        ... 17 more
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="EngFoxProPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.....BOM</class>
    <class>com.....INV</class> (Other classes)
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:dbf:/R:/DTCI/"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.hxtt.sql.dbf.DBFDriver"/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value=""/>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
      <property name="eclipselink.platform.class.name" value="com.hxtt.support.eclipselink.DbfPlatform"/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Notice that my database is linked to a network drive and it's just reading the data from files, not an actual database server.

I have verified that the classpath includes the eclipselink.jar and javax.persistence.jar.
I hope someone can give me something new to try. Thanks so much.

Comment: judging by the stack trace, the persistence.jar is on the classpath, but how are you sure that you have the EclipseLink.jar on there?  Check it has the org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider class incase you have an osgi jar renamed as eclipselink jar, and that all required classes and the persistence.xml file are also on the classpath correctly.  Try also setting the log level to Finest http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Comment: OK, so Thank you.  I found my problem.  It was that I had 2 eclipselink.jar files.  One for EclipseLink, but the other for my HXTT DBF driver.  HXTT provided the eclipselink.jar as a support for the driver.  I renamed the .jar to something else and it works!  Thanks so much!